# Code Map not working in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-map

I try to generate a Code Map for my solution but it blows up saying: `Unable to connect to the specified database`.

Specifically, it's trying to connect to (LocalDB)\v11.0

Why does it blow up and why does it need to connect to a DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow LocalDb was not installed - typically it gets installed with VS 2012.  So I installed [SQL Server Data Tools for VS2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015), which also installed LocalDb

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio uses a code index database to help store and create the code maps.